# how to choose a value from combobox and insert it into record in c#

Tags: c#, select, combobox, insert

Hello I'm new at c# And I Have a problem in the combo box .

I want the user to select a value from the combo box and using the value of the selected data, type some information in text boxes.

All the data should be saved in another table.

The combo box is populated from the Nationality table and the text boxes contain employees information .

The application uses sql server database and the forms are in c#.

Thanks
the code I came up with::::::::::

`enter code here`private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
 {
        try
        {
            ExPForm();
       string strConnectionString = @"Data Source = C:\\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security = SSPI; Initial Catalog = DB_Admin";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            string strExpCode = txtExpCode.Text.Trim();
            DateTime dtExpDate = dtPickerExpDate.Value;
            string strExpEmp = txtExpEmp.Text.Trim();
            string strExpGov = comboExpGov.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string strExpSubTitle = txtExpSubTitle.Text.Trim();
            string strExpSubSum = richtxtExpSubSum.Text.Trim();
             string strExpSubNote = txtExpSubNote.Text.Trim();
            string query = "INSERT INTO ExpTbl(ExpCode, ExpDate, ExpEmpName, GovID, OutInID,SubTypeID, LocID, ExpSubTitle, ExpSubSum, ExpSubNote)VALUES(@ExpCode, @ExpDate, @ExpEmpName, @GovID, OutInID,SubTypeID, LocID, @ExpSubTitle, @ExpSubSum, @ExpSubNote)";
            SqlCommand InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            InsertCommand.Connection = con;
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"strExpCode ", strExpCode);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"strExpDate ", strDate);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"GovID", GovID);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"strOutInID",2);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"SubTypeID", 2);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"LocID", 2);
        InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"strExpSubTitle ", strExpSubTitle);
        InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"strExpSubSum ", strExpSubSum);
        InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"strExpSubNote ", strExpSubNote);           
 InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("New record has been added successfully");
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it home work for us? - have you tried anything?

Comment: can you paste the code.. whatever you have done

Comment: I did the select part but the insert I'm stuck how to take the selected value and insert it in the save button

Comment: @MUAl-t still your code will help to understand what is going on..

Comment: I can't type it here it is to long

Comment: @MUAl-t you can edit your question, pls.

Comment: is this code correct !!! Please help!!!!